# how to send data to multiple destinations in Mininet?

Tags: multicast, mininet, sdn

I want to test my multicast routing algorithm implemented in the SDN controller. I'm generating my test network topology using Mininet emulator. 
According to my knowledge, there's no feature in Mininet which allows me to send packets from one sender to multiple destination (multicast). I've already tried to find the answer to that question in network, but i cannot find any. 
So, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Group Table that's supported by OpenFlow v1.3. Then you can do multicast by having a group table with multiple buckets and each bucket outputs to a designed port.

Update: Ryu igmp controller written in Python: https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/app/simple_switch_igmp.py